# Angular escaping some of the css properties

Tags: angularjs

I have webapp written in angular js. I am trying to load some HTML content in one of the div from my db. Following his how I told angular to trust HTML-

```
app = angular.module("######", ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize', 'UserValidation', 'ui.select', 'textAngular', 'infinite-scroll']);

app.filter("trust", ['$sce', function ($sce) {
    return function (htmlCode) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlCode);
    }
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<div class="summary" ng-bind-html="vm.portal.portalSummary | trust"></div>
```

**However some of the css properties from style attribute is getting escaped like position absolute, border.**

*1. The html is safe to be loaded, I too prohibit angular to escape these css styles?*

*2. Why angular is escaping these styles? What kind of security hazards are involved?*

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: did you checked that your data comes intact from your web service?

Comment: Please include an example of some HTML content and how it is being "escaped". Also, please limit yourself to a single question per post.

Comment: @Hitmands: Bulls Eye! Sorry I didn't check it before posting. Please answer the question, I will mark question right.

Answer (score 0):

@Hitmands has suggested right thing in comment, its was not a issue of angularjs, properties were being stripped on server side